# Microsoft Cognitive-Speaker Recognition - Verification profile - Create Enrollment

Tags: postman, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to make a call in Postman for the Microsoft Cognitive Service - Create Enrollment for Verification profile.

This is what I am using: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797

I have an API URL created: https://internspeaker.cognitiveservices.azure.com/spid/v1.0 And the Subscription-Key.

I started by using their testing console and all of them worked perfectly until the enrollment process where I have to add an audio file in a specific format (.WAV with different characteristics). The Microsoft console asked me for binary data for the audio file and I could not get the audio file converted. So I found another way of testing by using Postman.

I took all other processes and they worked perfectly until I tried Create Enrollment for the Verification Profile. Here I added all the details + the audio file but I could not pass the error(the error is shown in the next link)

This is the error I am getting:
[image: This is the error I am getting]

This is how I added the audio file in Postman:
[image: This is how I added the audio file in Postman]

This is a successful call with the same URL and subscription-Key:
[image: This is a successful call with the same URL and subscription-Key]

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is not in right format.

Your url should be `https://internspeaker.cognitiveservices.azure.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/{your identificationProfileId}/enroll`. You could find the success url format is correct.

And your way to add audio is fine.

Update:
if want to use verification profile to create enrollment, the url should be:`https://internspeaker.cognitiveservices.azure.com/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles/{your verificationProfileId}/enroll`.

Comment: The URL you sent is the URL for the Identification Profile. The one you sent worked perfectly with no problems.
I am trying for the Verification Profile
This is the link for the documentation: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/56406930e597ed20c8d8549c

As I can see, this is how to put the URL: https://{endpoint}/spid/v1.0/verificationProfiles/{verificationProfileId}/enroll
where the verificationProfileId is the one created with the Create Verification Profile

Comment: Sry, cause your first link is the Identification  profile to create enrollment, so I provide the link, if want to use verification profile  create enrollment, just replace the parameter `identificationProfiles ` with `verificationProfiles`  and the id.

Comment: @florinpatulea,  If this could help you , you could accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much . I saw that i was not putting the /verificationProfile in the API